# Jquery UI Dialog open on if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, dialog

I am creating a little game in jquery, where I want to show the user a little box, if they won the game.

The condition here is `(correctcards ==10)`
I tried to call dialog on it but it wont work.

Can anyone tell me why?

(I also aready tried to create a new div, when correctcards turn 10 and call dialog on it then, but it doesnt work as well)

```js
if (correctCards == 10) {
  endTime = new Date().getTime();
  time();
  console.log('Spiel endet');
  $('#myDialog2').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    buttons: {
      'Next Level': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      },
      'Close': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      },
    }
  })

}
```

```html
<div id="myDialog2">You won</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the dialog outside of your `if`.

```js
  $('#myDialog2').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    buttons: {
      'Next Level': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      },
      'Close': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      },
    }
  });

var correctCards = 10;

if (correctCards == 10) {
  console.log('Spiel endet');
  $('#myDialog2').dialog('open');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="myDialog2" style>You won</div>
```

Comment: that was easy! I almost feel bad for bothering you
Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind upvoting andaccepting the answer?